# How to use a local variable in other functions flask?

Tags: python, variables, flask

I have a function that I want to call each time a web visitor hits '/'(home page). I would also line to use the results of that function in other functions. Any recommendations on how to do this?

```
@app.route('/')
def home():
   store = index_generator() #This is the local variable I would like to use 
   return render_template('home.html')

 @app.route('/home_city',methods = ['POST'])
 def home_city():
   CITY=request.form['city']
   request_yelp(DEFAULT_LOCATION=CITY,data_store=store) """I would like to use the results here"""
   return render_template('bank.html')
```

Comment: you can set the `store` variable in the session.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See the [Flask session docs](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/quickstart/#sessions). You need to do some minor settings.

```
from flask import session

@app.route('/')
def home():
   store = index_generator()
   session['store'] = store
   return render_template('home.html')

 @app.route('/home_city',methods = ['POST'])
 def home_city():
   CITY=request.form['city']
   store = session.get('store')
   request_yelp(DEFAULT_LOCATION=CITY,data_store=store)
   return render_template('bank.html')
```